# how to connect to private network over internet?

Tags: vpn, private-network

I have a Linux system which has 2 interfaces, one for private network 172.16.x.x, another has public ip connected to Internet. How can I connect to other systems in 172.16.x.x from my Laptop having Windows via internet? I think i need to have VPN, but i don't care about security, is their any easy solution without buying any hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a software VPN server on your Linux system and they're all free.

`pptpd` only needs a couple of configuration files and you can even use simple plain-text passwords. There's no need to setup any kind of shared secret or certificate and the client is built-in to almost all internet-connected devices with a colour display.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is simply to use `iptables` NAT features if you only have specific systems + ports you want to expose on the public-facing interface.

If you need something quick and dirty without learning the syntax and concept of `iptables` (which is educational but involved), `rinetd` will work, again, assuming you only have specific systems + ports you want to expost on the public-facing interface.  I've found `rinetd` to be unstable under load, though.

If you want to access anything on the 172.16.0.0/24 subnet from outside, you're looking at needing some type of tunneling or VPN in the mix.  OpenVPN would be what I would recommend, or Adito if an SSL VPN sounds more to your liking.